# print bigrams learned with gensim

Tags: python, gensim, n-gram, topic-modeling, phrase

I want to learn bigrams from a corpus using gensim, and then just print the bigrams learned. i've not seen an example that does this.
help appreciated

```
from gensim.models import Phrases
documents = ["the mayor of new york was there", "human computer interaction and machine learning has now become a trending research area","human computer interaction is interesting","human computer interaction is a pretty interesting subject", "human computer interaction is a great and new subject", "machine learning can be useful sometimes","new york mayor was present", "I love machine learning because it is a new subject area", "human computer interaction helps people to get user friendly applications"]
sentence_stream = [doc.split(" ") for doc in documents]

bigram = Phrases(sentence_stream)

# how can I print all bigrams learned and just the bigrams, including "new_york" and "human computer" ?enter code here
```

Answer (score 4):

The answer by the OP will work if you are training the model using the class `Phrases` as mentioned and printing the bigrams without persisting the model. It will not work when you do save the model and then load it again in the future. When you load the model after saving it, you would need to use the `Phraser` class as follows:

```
from gensim.models.phrases import Phraser
```

and then load the model:

```
bigram_model = Phraser.load('../../whatever_bigram_model')
```

Then, if you do use the following method as the answer by the OP mentioned i.e.

**Answer by OP**

```
import operator
sorted(
    {k:v for k,v in bigram_model.vocab.items() if b'_' in k if v>=bigram_model.min_count}.items(),
    key=operator.itemgetter(1),
    reverse=True)
```

You will get an error stating:

```
AttributeError: 'Phraser' object has no attribute 'vocab'
```

**Solution**

The way around this is the following code:

```
for bigram in bigram_model.phrasegrams.keys():
    print(bigram)
```

**Output:**

```
(b'word1', b'word2')
(b'word3', b'word4')
```

This solution works in both situations, for a persisted and non-persisted model, in the example given by the OP, a modified version of my solution that works is:

```
for ngrams, _ in bigram.vocab.items():
    unicode_ngrams = ngrams.decode('utf-8')
    if '_' in unicode_ngrams:
        print(unicode_ngrams)
```

Gives:

```
the_mayor
mayor_of
of_new
new_york
york_was
was_there
human_computer
computer_interaction
interaction_and
and_machine
machine_learning
learning_has
has_now
now_become
```

*There is more in the output but I truncated it, in the interest of the length of this answer*

I hope my answer helps add clarity.

Answer (score 0):

```
import operator
sorted(
    {k:v for k,v in bigram.vocab.items() if b'_' in k if v>=bigram.min_count}.items(),
    key=operator.itemgetter(1),
    reverse=True)
```

Comment: I believe that might print all bigrams observed to have occurred more than `min_count` times, not necessarily those that would be composed-into-phrases. Take a look at the `export_phrases()` method (https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/2ccc82bf50bcfbee44932c160db076a873cf893e/gensim/models/phrases.py#L556), especially how it's used with `pseudocorpus()` inside `Phraser.__init__()` (https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/2ccc82bf50bcfbee44932c160db076a873cf893e/gensim/models/phrases.py#L805). That can express just the bigrams that'd be created in normal operation.

Comment: @gojomo I found pseudocorpus confusing, can you post a fuller answer?

Comment: You can just run the exact line linked – `for bigram, score in phrases_model.export_phrases(corpus, self.delimiter, as_tuples=True)` – to loop over ever bigram that would be promoted-to-a-phrase from the corpus. You could use your original corpus. You could use `.pseudocorpus()` to just make a fake corpus from all the seen bigrams – and thus express all phrases the model could possibly provide. If you need more guidance, describe what you've tried & what results you saw & how those differered from what you expected.

Comment: @gojomo what I find confusing is the need for any corpus _at all_. that is, a corpus has been used to learn bigrams. now I want to extract those learned bigrams. why do I need another corpus to do that?

Comment: The `Phrases` class alone just does one pass over the corpus, compiling stats on potential phrase-combinations. It's then ready, whenever presented with new texts, to combine bigrams. (It doesn't even maintain a compact list of just "combinable" bigrams, because it's possible to adjust the `threshold` later and change the mix.) If you want a list of actual bigrams, at current parameters, you need to iterate over, and test, all possibles. One way to do that is to repeat the original training corpus. Another way is to create a fake corpus-like list of all possibles (aka `pseudocorpus()`).

Comment: Set aside that it's called a 'corpus' - it's just a way to iterate over all possibles, to help `export_phrases()` work.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by the comments of gojomo. Here is a complete solution.

```
from gensim.models.phrases import Phrases, pseudocorpus

documents = ["the mayor of new york was there",
             "human computer interaction and machine learning has now become a trending research area",
             "human computer interaction is interesting","human computer interaction is a pretty interesting subject",
             "human computer interaction is a great and new subject",
             "machine learning can be useful sometimes",
             "new york mayor was present",
             "i love machine learning because it is a new subject area",
             "human computer interaction helps people to get user friendly applications"]

sentence_stream = [doc.split(" ") for doc in documents]

def get_all_bigrams(bigram_model):
    corpus =  pseudocorpus(bigram_model.vocab, bigram_model.delimiter, bigram_model.common_terms)
    bigrams = []
    for bigram, score in bigram_model.export_phrases(corpus, bigram_model.delimiter, as_tuples=False):     
        if score >= bigram_model.threshold:
            bigrams.append(bigram.decode('utf-8'))
    return bigrams

bigram = Phrases(sentence_stream, min_count=1)
bigrams = get_all_bigrams(bigram)
print(bigrams)
['new_york', 'human_computer', 'computer_interaction', 'machine_learning', 'is_a']
```